# Removing mount default execute permission of text files

Tags: permissions, linux-mint, mount, fstab

I want to mount all text files without execute permission to eliminate the (Run in Terminal - Display - Run) message, which appears every time I open a text file in Linux Mint.

I have the following line in my fstab:

```
/dev/sda7       /media/myname/Programs   ntfs-3g defaults,uid=1000    0   0
```

I tried to add `umask=111` but all files had the permission displayed as -????????? and I lost the access to all files.

Comment: Have you tried option `noexec`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS-Windows sets the execute bit on every file. (One of the reasons for its poorer security).

`noexec` is the option to disable excitability. Using the umask will stop directories from being traversable, because directories need execute permission.

Therefore mount with option `noexec`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm. However, the command ls -l outputs a weird result; the permission characters still have the the x permission but the file cannot be executed!

Comment: When you say weird, do you mean inconsistent? This is expected, it shows the settings of the files, not of the mount-point.

Comment: Thanks @ctrl-alt-delor. For me, this is the first time to know that the mount point has its own permission.

Answer (score -1):

You could simply add the ro mount option, which stands for "read-only".

More information can be found by typing `man fstab` and `man mount`.